# MYSQL - How to save a value without removing the right zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table to register vehicles.

One of the columns is to save the **price (type double)** in that format 90.000 for example. But when I enter the values in the bank it saves and removes the last zero and becomes 90.

How do I make the value equal to the original 90.000?

Comment: price is never double. It's why DECIMAL was invented. Also, you're confusing data storage with data display.

Comment: If you want to store ninety thousand, enter 90000. If you then want to display 90.000,00 see FORMAT()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the field type DECIMAL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: I insert an value 90.000 but mysql saved 90.00

Comment: What did you specify the DECIMAL size parameters as?

Something like 4,3 should work.